# ML Engine - Slow Inference Time

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

From Google Cloud Documentation we have

> Cloud Machine Learning Engine online prediction is a service optimized
>   to run your data through hosted models with as little latency as
>   possible. You send small batches of data to the service and it returns
>   your predictions in the response. You can learn more general
>   information about online prediction with the other prediction
>   concepts.
>   Blockquote

https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/online-predict

And my experience with it is sub-par I must say. Don't get me wrong, I love ML Engine and I do a whole lot of training there, but in my experience, the inference time is ridiculous.

I've made a small semantic segmentation network on images of size 256x256. I'm using Estimators and I convert the model to a SavedModel format, then make predictions using this code

```
predictor_fn = tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model(
    export_dir=saved_model_dir,
    signature_def_key="prediction"
)
```

On my computer, this gave me inference time around 0.9 seconds. I tried the same code on a Datalab instance, with machine-type of **n1-highmem-2** which gave me inference time of around 2.3 seconds.

Now, if I serve my saved model on ML-Engine instead

```
gcloud ml-engine models create SEM --regions europe-west1
gcloud ml-engine versions create SEM --model V0 --origin "MY_BUCKET_PATH" --runtime-version=1.6
```

And the serving input function is so:

```
def parse_incoming_tensors(incoming):
    img = vgg16_normalize(tf.reshape(incoming, [-1, 256, 256, 3]))
    return img


def serving_input_fn_web():
    """Input function to use when serving the model on ML Engine."""
    inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=(None, ))
    feature_input = batch_base64_to_tensor(inputs)
    feature_input = {'img': parse_incoming_tensors(feature_input)}

    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(feature_input, inputs)
```

Then, I make predictions using this class:

```
class MakeQuery():
    def __init__(self, project, model, version=None, client_secret=None):
        # Set the environment variable
        secret_path = os.path.abspath('./client_secret.json')
        os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = secret_path

        # Create service object and prepare the name of the model we are going to query
        self._service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('ml', 'v1')
        self._name = 'projects/{}/models/{}'.format(project, model)
        self._project = self._service.projects()

        if version is not None:
            self._name += '/versions/{}'.format(version)

    def predict(self, instances):
        response = self._project.predict(name=self._name, body=instances).execute()

        if 'error' in response:
            raise RuntimeError(response['error'])

        return response

    def get_prediction(self, img_arrays):
        input_list = [{'input': array_to_base64_websafe_resize(img)} for img in img_arrays]
        input_format = {'instances': input_list}

        return self.predict(input_format)
```

Then each prediction request takes 10 seconds! Is ML-Engine seriously deploying the model every single time I make a request?

**TL;DR**
Using Tensorflow SavedModel format from Estimators, the inference time on Google ML-Engine is very slow.

- Razer 2017: 0.9s
- Datalab n1-highmem-2: 2.3 seconds
- ML-Engine 10 seconds

Comment: Do you mind reaching out to us at cloudml-feedback@ and reference this post?

Comment: @rhaertel80 sure, I'll do it now :)